# Including PepperFlash in electron not working when built in production

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an Electron application that needs to load a flash based website, i have included the PepperFlash DLL in windows and it works when I run un-packed, but when I run packed the plugin doesn't work.

I've made sure that the file exists in the path it's looking at when built

```
let pluginPath = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL ?
    path.join(__dirname, pluginName):
    __dirname.replace('app.asar', 'app.asar.unpacked') + pluginName;
```

and if I console.log plugin path when built it gives me the proper area.

```
C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Temp\nsl129A.tmp\app\resources\app.asar.unpacked\buildpepflashplayer.dll
```

which exists when I navigate to that area correctly.

I am also including plugins in WebPreferences and this does work when unpacked.

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      title: 'TST Application',
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/logo.png'),
      webPreferences: {
          plugins: true,
          webSecurity: false
      },
      show: false
  });
```

In my package.json for electron-builder I have the proper asarUnpack}

```
 "asarUnpack": [
     "build/pepflashplayer.dll"
 ],
```

but when I try and load the url

```
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/');
```

I get **Couldn't load plugin.**

however one thing I noticed was travelling to http://isflashinstalled.com/ indicated that flash was correctly installed. As well, In my renderer process if I console.log

```
        console.log(navigator.plugins);
```

I see the flash plugin in the list of plugins.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I was packaging in 32-bit and using the 64-bit PepperFlash DLL, made the switch out and things started working.